# What's the right way to assess an ML algo on Precision Recall values?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, precision

So I know what Precision and Recall stand for.

Precision optimizes for False Positives and Recall False Negatives. In the end what is the cost objective of a business that should be taken into account. Like for a hospital you might want to have a algo with high recall (low false negatives) as the cost to missing out on identifying a malignant tumor is more than having to do more investigation on those false alarms.

But what is still considered decent Precision/Recall metrics? Like I have a Binary Classification algo, which has 0.34 as Precision, but Recall is 0.98. Even if business objective favors optimizes on favoring False Negatives (high recall), is this ok to consider such a algo which although favors High recall but has poor Precision values.

Note: I had a severe class imbalance problems with around 99% of obs 0 and just under 1% being 1 class.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is highly dependent on the context, but let's assume this classifier detects malignant tumors at very early stages where it's quite hard to detect.

Now for the purpose of this analysis, let's have two scenarios with two different assumptions.

**Scenario 1: The system will be used as a quick filtering phase on a huge number of people to quickly dismiss those who are not suspects of tumors**

Well in that case, this model with .98 recall will rarely let a person with a tumor slip by undetected, and this is the main purpose of the system since it's merely a quick filtering phase to dismiss a considerable portion of the population, since the following inspections are quite costly and time consuming.

I would say this system would do pretty well in that scenario

**Scenario 2: The system will be used to diagnose people with tumor that will be directly enlisted in costly treatment programs**

In this fictional scenario, the system is meant to be very confident and precise on those who are classified with tumors since there is no post-filtering phases after this one and the treatments will be both costly and might cause pretty harmful side-effects for those who aren't cancer fighters.

In that case, this model would perform terribly for the purpose it was meant for in this scenario.

So it's totally dependent on the case, in scenario number 1, it's totally fine to go with low precision as long as the recall it very high, of course the higher the precision is better, but as long as it doesn't fall below a certain threshold for the recall.

While for scenario 2, it's expected to have a very high precision, even if the recall is too low, .99 precision with .05 recall is totally fine in that scenario.

**UPDATE 1**

Regarding the class imbalance that your dataset suffers from, this could be a direct influence on the bad precision for the under-samples class, have you tried using weighted loss, where the under-sampled class have higher weights that should help in balancing the class affect during training.

There are many techniques that can be used to handle imbalanced datasets, you can read more about them [here](https://www.datascience.com/blog/imbalanced-data)

Comment: All this metrics is after using class weights in algo.